# Character Segmentation fails on 'W'

Tags: opencv, ocr, contour

I am using OpenCV for OCR of printed codes containing arbitrary characters and numbers. My pipeline involves thresholding, denoising, gradient morphology, and then finding the contours in order to palce a bounding box around each letter.

It works very well except when a 'W' appears in the code. It usually places 2 or 3 bounding boxes such that the prediction is "VAV" or "VV", which is honestly a mistake my own eyes might make when I'm tired.

Does anyone have any ideas how best to address this issue? I can be fairly certain that a 'W' appears in many of these codes and it needs to be segmented properly. Thanks for any help!

Comment: post your code and sample image.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that worked, at least in my case. I iteratively compute the relative overlap of neighboring bounding boxes, combining bounding boxes that have an overlap greater than a specified threshold (0.15 in my case). This works very effectively for my data.

Here is a cropping as an example:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try running a morphological dilation on the image before finding the contours. This will help you merge all the parts of the letter W as a single blob, preventing it from being recognized as multiple letters.

Comment: Unfortunately the morphological dilation had minimal improvement on segmenting the 'W' and also caused 'J' and 'O' to be combined. But I found another solution for my case

Comment: i am glad you managed to solved your problem. Do share a screenshot of your data so we can all see what the problem was.